# Connect two classes, and assign a value to object

Tags: python, class

I have 2 classes. First hold's users age and second hold's users name. Is it possible to make them works ?

```
class Uinfo:

    ThisAge = 0


class UUser:

    info = Uinfo()

    name = None


newUser = UUser()
newUser.name = "john"
newUser.info[0].ThisAge = 23
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do or why you think you need a separate object to store a user's age. In any case this is not going to work because you're instantiating `Uinfo` once for the entire `UUser` class so all user objects will share the same age. You may want to read a little further on how object orientation works in Python, and look at some more code examples.

Comment: This is not how classes should be used. Among other things,  you are using class attributes instead of instance attributes.

Comment: What does "make them work" mean? What are they supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

OK, assignment to instances of a class in Python.  Easy.  My last answer was totally wrong. :)

```
class Uinfo:

    ThisAge = 0


class UUser:
    def __init__(self):
        self.info = Uinfo()
    info = None
    name = None


newUser = UUser()
newUser.name = "john"
newUser.info.ThisAge = 23
newUser2 = UUser()
newUser2.name = "oe"
newUser2.info.ThisAge = 34

print(newUser.name)
print(newUser.info.ThisAge)
print(newUser2.name)
print(newUser2.info.ThisAge)
```

Notice that the UUser class now has a constructor that assigns a UNIQUE INSTANCE of the Uinfo class.  Job done.

I'd like to make the point that, this answer, answers the exact question the OP asks (It makes it work...)  Any "should have done this" or "should have done that" is besides the point.  I believe the OP should look into how to use instance references and when to use aliasing, and should definitely read the https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html documentation, as I have not, and I care not to.